# To filter array values it already exist to show alert box with msg?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The task is to filter array values is already exist to filter duplicate value then show a alert box with msg otherwise to add data then append table.

please give some solution or tips guys.

```js
function pushData() {
  const products = [];
  const data = {
    id: document.getElementById('id').value,
    name: document.getElementById('name').value,
    qty: document.getElementById('qty').value,
    price: document.getElementById('price').value,
    total: document.getElementById('total').value

  }
  products.push(data);
  $.each(products, function(key, value) {
    $('#display').append(`
        <tr>
        <td>${value.id}</td>
        <td>${value.name}</td>
        <td>${value.qty}</td>
        <td>${value.price}</td>
        <td>${value.total}</td>
        </tr>`)
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color:pink ;">
  <label for="id">ID</label>
  <input style="display:block" type="number" id="id" class="getVal" /></br>
  
  <label>NAME:</label>
  <input style="display:block" type="Name" id="name" class="getVal"></br>
  
  <label for="qty">QTY:</label>
  <input style="display:block" type="Qty" id="qty" class="getVal" /></br>
  
  <label for="price">PRICE:</label>
  <input style="display:block" type="price" id="price" class="getVal" /></br>
  
  <label for="price">TOTAL PRICE:</label>
  <input style="display:block" type="price" id="total" class="getVal" /></br>
  
  <button onclick="pushData()">ADD</button>
</div>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>QTY</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>TOTAL PRICE</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="display"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and also please inform us if you want it to look at all columns or just some of them for duplicates.

Comment: all columns sir or unique id in this same the data was didn't add to show alert box msg with is already exist then add this data qty only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one using some method you can filter and display alert if product is already present.

```js
let products = [];
  function pushData() {
    const data = {
      id: document.getElementById('id').value,
      name: document.getElementById('name').value,
      qty: document.getElementById('qty').value,
      price: document.getElementById('price').value,
      total: document.getElementById('total').value
    }

    if (products.some(item => item.id == document.getElementById('id').value)) {
      alert('Product already exist!');
      return;
    } else {
      products = [];
      products.push(data);
    }

    $.each(products, function (key, value) {
      $('#display').append(`
        <tr>
        <td>${value.id}</td>
        <td>${value.name}</td>
        <td>${value.qty}</td>
        <td>${value.price}</td>
        <td>${value.total}</td>
        </tr>`)
    })
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color:pink ;">
  <label for="id">ID</label>
  <input style="display:block" type="number" id="id" class="getVal" /></br>

  <label>NAME:</label>
  <input style="display:block" type="Name" id="name" class="getVal"></br>

  <label for="qty">QTY:</label>
  <input style="display:block" type="Qty" id="qty" class="getVal" /></br>

  <label for="price">PRICE:</label>
  <input style="display:block" type="price" id="price" class="getVal" /></br>

  <label for="price">TOTAL PRICE:</label>
  <input style="display:block" type="price" id="total" class="getVal" /></br>

  <button onclick="pushData()">ADD</button>
</div>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>QTY</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>TOTAL PRICE</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="display"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think it would be better to do `item.id == data.id` rather than `item.id == document.getElementById('id').value`

Comment: yes you can also use what @CarstenLøvboAndersen commented

Comment: sir please some codes to how use filter methods in this functions

Comment: use filter method then check duplicate id

Comment: filter methods to use this form with example codes sir